# CipherInputStream only read 16 bytes (AES/Java)

Tags: java, encryption, stream, aes

I'm using CipherInputStream and CipherOutputStream to encrypt files using AES.

`encrypt(...)` seems to be working fine, but my `decrypt(...)` function only decrypt the first 16 bytes of my files.

Here is my class :

```
public class AESFiles {

    private byte[] getKeyBytes(final byte[] key) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(key, 0, keyBytes, 0, Math.min(key.length, keyBytes.length));
        return keyBytes;
    }

    public Cipher getCipherEncrypt(final byte[] key) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        return cipher;
    }

    public Cipher getCipherDecrypt(byte[] key) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        return cipher;
    }

    public void encrypt(File inputFile, File outputFile, byte[] key) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = getCipherEncrypt(key);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        CipherOutputStream cos = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int read = fis.read(data);
            while (read != -1) {
                cos.write(data, 0, read);
                read = fis.read(data);
                System.out.println(new String(data, "UTF-8").trim());
            }
            cos.flush();
        } finally {
            fos.close();
            cos.close();
            fis.close();
        }
    }

    public void decrypt(File inputFile, File outputFile, byte[] key) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = getCipherDecrypt(key);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        CipherInputStream cis = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int read = cis.read(data);
            while (read != -1) {
                fos.write(data, 0, read);
                read = cis.read(data);
                System.out.println(new String(data, "UTF-8").trim());
            }
        } finally {
            fos.close();
            cis.close();
            fis.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        byte[] key = "mykey".getBytes("UTF-8");
        new AESFiles().encrypt(new File("C:\\Tests\\secure.txt"), new File("C:\\Tests\\secure.txt.aes"), key);
        new AESFiles().decrypt(new File("C:\\Tests\\secure.txt.aes"), new File("C:\\Tests\\secure.txt.1"), key);
    }
}
```

So my question is, why the `decrypt` function only read the first 16 bytes ?

Comment: How do you know it decrypts only 16 bytes?   Can you edit your post to show the exception you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any exception. The size of the file "secure.txt.1" (decrypted files) has only 16 bytes, while the source has 41 bytes.

Comment: Note that using `CipherInputStream` is very tricky as it sweeps exceptions under the carpet (that's a proverb meaning that it hides them). I would not use it myself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is very subtle.  Your problem is that you are closing your `fos` *before* your `cos`.   In your `encrypt(...)` method you are doing:

```
} finally {
    fos.close();
    cos.close();
    fis.close();
}
```

That closes the `FileOutputStream` out from under the `CipherOutputStream` so the final padded block of encrypted output never gets written to the output file.  If you close the `fos` *after* the `cos` then your code should work fine.

Really, you should consider doing something like:

```
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    CipherOutputStream cos = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
        // once cos wraps the fos, you should set it to null
        fos = null;
        ...
    } finally {
        if (cos != null) {
           cos.close();
        }
        if (fos != null) {
           fos.close();
        }
        if (fis != null) {
           fis.close();
        }
    }
```

FYI: `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils` has a great `closeQuietly(...)` method which handles `null` checks and catches the exceptions for you.

Comment: By now this can be handled by using try-with-resources. Note that you can specify multiple streams in the `try` statement, which will be closed automatically and - of course - in the right (reverse) order.

Comment: saved my life, but could you please explain why this happening ?

Comment: Like the answer says @Karoly "so the final padded block of encrypted output never gets written to the output file".  You close the file before the `CipherOutputStream` is done with it.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am so confused. For some reason I making some stupid mistake and there is 1 byte difference between the encrypted and the original file. I have no idea why! I will post a question on Monday and might ask for your help boys. Thx

Comment: @Gray: could you please check this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420936/different-bytes-are-returned-when-decrypt-files-content